# How to add a counter in Java?

Tags: java

The app stops. Where am I wrong? The button when clicked change the text to the number of times the item was clicked.

```
private Button button;
int countClicks = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countClicks++;
            button.setText(countClicks);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what's the problem ? ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a classic mistake

You are using `View.setText()` on an `int`, and it needs to be on a `String`.
Try

```
 button.setText(countClicks + "");
```

By concatenating the integer with an empty String, it will auto-cast it to a String

Comment: @student your welcome! If the answer helped you, please upvote the answer and hit the little check mark to accept the answer

Comment: I'd just like to point out why this mistake wasn't caught by the compiler: setText has an overload that takes an int, which is supposed to be the ID of a string to use. A perfect example of why reading the documentation for methods you use is always important.

Comment: @YonahKarp Np. You're right though, this does appear to be a common mistake. Makes me wonder why the method doesn't throw if out can't find a string to reference.